# Авторизация на Angular 2

Tags: angular2, typescript

Хочу сделать авторизацию не по email, а по логину но в итоге не чего не получается. Авторизация так же происходит по email. Как можно сделать авторизацию не по email, а логину?

Sign-in.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output,Input, ViewChild, EventEmitter, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth/auth.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import {getErrorTextFromJSON} from "../../shared/functions";
import {ToastsManager} from "ng2-toastr";


declare const $: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  signInUser = {
    login: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  @Output() onFormResult = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
    protected authService:AuthService, 
    private router:Router,
    public toastManager: ToastsManager,
    vcr: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    toastManager.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
   }


  ngOnInit() {
  }


  logOut(){
    this.authService.logOutUser().subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/sign-in']));
  }

  onSignInSubmit(){


    this.authService.logInUser(this.signInUser).subscribe(

        res => {
          if(res.status == 200){
            // loginForm.resetForm();
            this.onFormResult.emit({signedIn: true, res});
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          }
        },

        err => {
          console.log('err:', err);

          // loginForm.resetForm();
          this.onFormResult.emit({signedIn: false, err});
          this.toastManager.error(getErrorTextFromJSON(err.json()), 'Ошибка');
        }
    )

  }

}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Angular2TokenService} from "angular2-token";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Response} from "@angular/http";


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  userSignedIn$:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private authService:Angular2TokenService) {
    this.userSignedIn$.next(this.authService.userSignedIn());

  }

  logOutUser():Observable<Response>{

    return this.authService.signOut().map(
        res => {
          this.userSignedIn$.next(false);
          return res;
        }
    );
  }

  logInUser(signInData: {login:string, email:string, password:string}):Observable<Response>{

    return this.authService.signIn(signInData).map(
        res => {
          this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
          return res
        }
    );

  }

   registerUser(signUpData:  {login:string, email:string, password:string, passwordConfirmation:string}):Observable<Response>{
    return this.authService.registerAccount(signUpData).map(
        res => {
          this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
          return res
        }
    );
  }


}
```

html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="signIn()" #f="ngForm" >
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group form-success label-floating is-empty">
         <input id="login" type="text" required name='login' [(ngModel)]="signInUser.login" class="form-control">
         <label class="control-label" for="login">Логин</label>
     </div>              
     <div class="form-group form-success label-floating is-empty">
       <input id="password" type="password" required name='password' [(ngModel)]="signInUser.password" class="form-control">
       <label class="control-label" for="password">Пароль</label>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
       <button type="submit" [disabled]="!(f.valid)" [ngClass]="{'disabled': !(f.valid)}" class="btn btn-success">Войти</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, это сервер решает, по логину или емайл проводить авторизацию.

Comment: Как всё таки бэк то реализован?